# Clearing input fields of a child component when the select option is changed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-forms

My problem basically is that I have a form and within that form.

I have a dropdown **<select />** and the **form dynamically changes** when the type is switched

```
          <select
            name="Type_Switcher"
            id="type_switch"
            onChange={handleOptionChange}
            
            
          >
            <option value={options[0]}>{options[0]}</option>
            <option value={options[1]}>{options[1]}</option>
            <option value={options[2]}>{options[2]}</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <div id="product_specification">
            {selectedOption === options[0] && <DVDForm optionChanged={optionChanged} register={register} />}
            {selectedOption === options[1] && <FurnitureForm optionChanged={optionChanged} register={register} />}
            {selectedOption === options[2] && <BookForm  optionChanged={optionChanged}  register={register}/>}

        </div>
```

**Here's the function that triggers when the option changes**

```
 function clearInput() {
    // Replace 'your-element-id' with the ID of your target HTML element
    var targetElement = $("#product_form_field");
    // Select all input-type child elements of the target element and clear their values
    console.log(targetElement)
    targetElement.find('input').val("");
  }
//   console.log(value)
  const handleOptionChange = (event) => {
    clearInput() // first clear off the input fields 
    setselectedOption(event.target.value);
    setOptionChanged(true);
    onChange(event);
  };
```

**And here's an example of a child component for one of the options :**

```
const DVDForm = ({ onChange, value, register, optionChanged }) => {
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (optionChanged && inputRef.current) {
        inputRef.current.value = '';
      }
    }, [optionChanged]);
  return (
    <label htmlFor='size' className='product_form_field' id='product_form_field'>
      <p>Size (MB)</p>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        name="size"
        id="size"
        placeholder="Enter size of the product"
        // onChange={onChange}
        // value={value.type?.size}
        {...register("type.size", { required: true})}
        

      />
      <span className='product_description'>Please provide size in MB</span>
    </label>
```

**Please Note:** I'm using react-hook-form so I'm not able to set the field with the traditional way of linking value and onChange props to the input field to manipulate it

I have tried solutions including ( `JQuery find('input').val('')`, and `form.reset()`  ) as long with many other solutions that didn't work